# Insert a file to a particular folder using google-drive-api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I tried as given below.
But the file is going to root directory(My-Drive).

```
var metadata = {
  'title': fileData.fileName,
  'mimeType': contentType,
  'parents':["0B6NmmF3ovpsbExuOEc1R2JzSFEp"] // It is one of my folder's id.
};

var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    base64Data +
    close_delim;

var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'POST',
    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
    },
    'body': multipartRequestBody});

 request.execute(callback);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved the issue.

The error was in this line:

```
'parents':["0B6NmmF3ovpsbExuOEc1R2JzSFEp"]
```

The line should be:

```
'parents':[{"id":"0B6NmmF3ovpsbExuOEc1R2JzSFEp"}]
```

Documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder

Answer (score 4):

The API has since changed and now takes an array, as in:

```
{
  name: '2022-11-16 1:3:7.mp3',
  parents: [ '1nQMLZ__yhRhrvWgrWp3roewNsoMx2dFv' ]
}
```